# Upload data on Google Cloud from an url

Tags: machine-learning, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to upload a dataset from a public url to a Google Cloud Machine Learning project, what is the easiest way?

This is the source url https://www.kaggle.com/c/carvana-image-masking-challenge/download/train.zip

There's an easy solution as the following code example (not working)?

```
gsutil cp https://www.kaggle.com/c/carvana-image-masking-challenge/download/train.zip train.zip
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[gsutil cp](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp) command is able to copy files between the local machine where gsutil is running and Google Cloud storage. (It is not supporting external URLs as source or destination.
If you download the zip file to your local computer, then you can upload to Cloud Storage via gsutil.

It's likely faster if you do this on a Cloud instance, depending on the size of the ZIP.

> When transferring data from an on-premise location, use **gsutil**.
>
> When transferring data from another cloud storage provider, use **[Storage Transfer Service](https://cloud.google.com/storage/transfer/)**.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Unfortunately, the dataset is too large to use my upload connection. I'll have to learn how to use the Transfer Service.